# jQuery - hiding an element when on a certain page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this wizard step form that I simulated with `<ul>` list items by overlapping inactive `<li>` items with absolute positioning.

The wizard form is working as desired except that I want to hide **next** or **previous** button on a certain step.

This is my logic in jQuery but it doesn't do any good.

```
if (index === 0) {
    $('#prev').addClass(invisible);
    $('#prev').removeClass(visible);
} else if (index === 1) {
    $('#prev').addClass(visible);
    $('#prev').removeClass(invisible);
} else {
   $('#next').addClass(invisible);
}
```

To get the index value I used `eq()` chained on a current step element like the following

```
var current;
var index = 0; 

$(function () {
   current = $('.pg-wrapper').find('.current');

$('#next').on('click', function() {
  if (current.next().length===0) return;

   current.next().addClass('current').show();
   current.removeClass('current').hide();

   navstep.next().addClass('active');
   navstep.removeClass('active');

   current = current.next();
   navstep = navstep.next();
   index = current.eq();
});
```

I tried to isolate it as much as possible but my full code will give you a better idea.
If you would care to assist please check my [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/oxamOBA/11/edit)

Comment: Quotes? addClass("visible") and you need to test on each click

Comment: By index, you mean different pages?
Like when index is 0, page is homepage, index is 1 then next page and so on.
Is it so?

Comment: @AwaisUmar Yes, it refers to pages of which I did as unordered list items. Because `eq()` is zero based, index 0 means the first list item.

Comment: @SeongLee, Let me create a snippet for you..maybe that will work for you...

Comment: Strange. I want to give upvote to people generously contributed to my question but if I do click upvote, it becomes -1 and says my vote is locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several issues

1. you used .eq instead of index
2. you were missing quotes around the class names
3. your navigation logic was flawed
4. no need to have two classes to change visibility

I believe the following is an improvement, but let me know if you have questions.

I added class="navBut" to the prev/next and rewrote the setting of the visibility

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8vLWE/)

```
var current;
var navstep;

$(function () {
  current = $('.pg-wrapper').find('.current');
  navstep=$('.nav-step').find('.active');
  $('.pg-wrapper div').not(current).hide();
  setBut(current);

  $('.navBut').on('click', function() {
    var next = this.id=="next";  
    if (next) { 
      if (current.next().length===0) return;
      current.next().addClass('current').show();
      navstep.next().addClass('active');
    }    
    else {
      if (current.prev().length===0) return;
      current.prev().addClass('current').show();
      navstep.prev().addClass('active');
    }  
    current.removeClass('current').hide();
    navstep.removeClass('active');
    current = (next)?current.next():current.prev();
    navstep = (next)?navstep.next():navstep.prev();
    setBut(current);
  });
});

function setBut(current) {
  var index=current.index();
  var max = current.parent().children().length-1;
  $('#prev').toggleClass("invisible",index<1);
  $('#next').toggleClass("invisible",index>=max);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your thorough contribution. I'm very happy with your input that suggests better practice with scalability in mind. Great learning.

Answer (score 1):

The `eq` function will not give you the index, for that you need to use the [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function.

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked at the whole code but shouldn't your class assignemnts look like:

```
$('#prev').addClass('invisible');
$('#prev').removeClass('visible');
```

i.e. with quotes around the class names? And is it really necessary to have a class `visible`? Assigning and removing the class `invisible` should easily do the job (provided the right styles have been set for this class).

Answer (score 0):

You should make 4 modifications.

1) Use .index() instead of .eq();

2) Add a function `changeIndex` which changes the class depends on the index and call it on click of prev and next.

3) add quotes to invisible and visible

4) There is a bug in your logic, try going to 3rd step and come back to 1st step. Both buttons will disappear. So you have to make next button visible if index = 0

Here is the demo :
http://jsfiddle.net/ChaitanyaMunipalle/9SzWB/

Comment: Your fiddle does not have a next button visible

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to update the fiddle. Now it is updated. Thanks

Comment: You need to save as base too

Answer (score 0):

Use index() function instead of eq() because eq() will return object and index() will return the integer value.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/saranyaciet/p929U/)

```
var current;
var navstep;
var index = 0;

$(function () {
   current = $('.pg-wrapper').find('.current');
  navstep=$('.nav-step').find('.active');
  $('.pg-wrapper div').not(current).hide();
}(jQuery));


$('#next').on('click', function() {
  if (current.next().length===0) return;
  current.next().addClass('current').show();

  current.removeClass('current').hide();

    navstep.next().addClass('active');
  navstep.removeClass('active');

 current = current.next();
  navstep = navstep.next();
  index = current.index();
  change_step(index)
});

$('#prev').on('click', function() {
  if (current.prev().length===0) return;
  current.prev().addClass('current').show();
  current.removeClass('current').hide();

  navstep.prev().addClass('active');
  navstep.removeClass('active');

  current = current.prev();
  navstep = navstep.prev();
  index = current.index();
  change_step(index)
});

function change_step(value)
{
    if (value === 0) {
        $('#prev').hide();
        $('#next').show();
    } else if (value === 1) {
        $('#prev').show();
        $('#next').show();
    } else {
       $('#next').hide();
       $('#prev').show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hide/show is not a good idea since the nav will move when prev is hidden

Comment: Get the count of step divs and check with the count.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to give you one too, but your fiddle is still not showing a next and neither there nor here are you using classes to show/hide the buttons

Comment: There is next and previous button and I had used addClass, removeClass

Comment: Aha. It is my Chrome that hides the next button under the field. I still see hide/show in function change_step

Comment: That function is never used. It has been used previously. So if they need, they can use it.

Comment: Ok, that was confusing - your function is hiding under the old function. I did not think to scroll further down